# How to infer type (for mypy & IDE) from a marshmallow schema?

Tags: python, types, mypy, pydantic, marshmallow

I have not asked a Python question in years! Exciting. This is largely an ecosystem question. Consider this snippet:

```py
try:
    result = schema.load(data)
except marshmallow.ValidationError as exc:
    sys.exit(f'schema validation failed: {exc}')
```

with `schema` being a `marshmallow.Schema`.

From `mypy`'s point of view, `result` is of type `Any`.

What options do I have so that `result` gets typed based on `schema`?

I have searched the web quite a bit, and my conclusion for now is that there is no such magic in the marshmallow ecosystem. Seemingly, there are solutions for the inverse (derive a marshmallow schema from e.g. a dataclass). But somehow I also suspect I am just missing something really obvious. But if there really is no solution for marshmallow: is the answer maybe to use e.g. pydantic to define the schema (and then get some beautiful magic for automatically inferred types that mypy can use)?

To maybe show an inspiration. In the JavaScript/TypeScript ecosystem there is yup, and here we have the derive-type-from-schema in the [quickstart](https://github.com/jquense/yup#getting-started) docs: `type User = InferType<typeof userSchema>;`

Comment: Please provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it stands your code is not complete and not reproducible. Include example input, desired output and actual output (of `mypy` or whatever) as well please. Right now I don't understand what exactly you want `mypy` to infer.

Comment: Most importantly, what is the _actual_ (i.e. runtime) type of `result`? Do you have some [`post_load`](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/marshmallow.decorators.html#marshmallow.decorators.post_load) hook that turns the output of `load` into an instance of some specific class? If so, that needs to be part of your code/question.

Comment: Related to [@DaniilFajnberg's question on GH](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/issues/2108).

Answer (score 1):

Initially I was not sure what exactly you meant in your question, but I think we cleared that up, so allow me to specify it a bit for the people that did not follow [this issue](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/issues/2108).

---

### Question

Say we have a model class looks like this (taken from the [`marshmallow` docs](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#declaring-schemas)):

```py
class User:
    def __init__(self, name: str, email: str) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.email = email

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return "<User(name={self.name!r})>".format(self=self)
```

The documentation section [*Deserializing to Objects*](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#deserializing-to-objects) suggest the following setup for the schema:

```py
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, post_load
# ... import User


class UserSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.Str()
    email = fields.Email()

    @post_load
    def make_user(self, data, **kwargs):
        return User(**data)


user_data = {"name": "Ronnie", "email": "ronnie@stones.com"}
schema = UserSchema()
result = schema.load(user_data)
```

If you were to add `reveal_type(result)` and run `mypy` over the code, it would give you `Any` as the type.

What can we do, to have a static type checker infer `result` to be an instance of `User` instead?

---

### Answer

As explained in [this issue](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/issues/2108), there is **no built-in typing functionality** for this in the `marshmallow` core. Since deserialization can be hooked into via `@post_load` methods at any point, the output type is undetermined. In its purest form (without such a hook) it would simply give us a dictionary. So the `Any` return makes sense.

However, if we want to restrict ourselves to *only* ever deserialize to specific class instances, we can define a subclass of the `marshmallow.Schema` and make it **generic** in terms of the model it deals with, which is what I suggested as a feature for `marshmallow`.

Since my proposal to include that in the core was politely rejected, I wrote that extension to the `marshmallow` ecosystem myself: [`marshmallow-generic`](https://github.com/daniil-berg/marshmallow-generic) (issues welcome!)

With the `GenericSchema` you can do the following:

```py
from marshmallow_generic import GenericSchema, fields
# ... import User


class UserSchema(GenericSchema[User]):
    name = fields.Str()
    email = fields.Email()


user_data = {"name": "Monty", "email": "monty@python.org"}
schema = UserSchema()
single_user = schema.load(user_data)
print(single_user)  # <User(name='Monty')>

json_data = '''[
    {"name": "Monty", "email": "monty@python.org"},
    {"name": "Ronnie", "email": "ronnie@stones.com"}
]'''
multiple_users = schema.loads(json_data, many=True)
print(multiple_users)  # [<User(name='Monty')>, <User(name='Ronnie')>]
```

Adding `reveal_type(single_user)` and `reveal_type(multiple_users)` at the bottom and running that code through `mypy` would yield the following output:

```
note: Revealed type is "User"
note: Revealed type is "builtins.list[User]"
```

That way we get the typing support we wanted and there is not even any need to write an explicit `@post_load` hook. All we need is to pass our `User` model as the type argument to `GenericSchema` and it will auto-magically convert to `User`.

---

Something as general as the TypeScript way you mentioned is not (currently or in the foreseeable future) possible in Python because the Python type system (unlike that of TypeScript) is fundamentally *nominal*, not *structural*. But we can work with what we have.

Comment: Daniil, this is amazing! I mean, I have not tried this out yet but I honestly appreciate your effort and hope I will find the time to give this a closer look. Thank you for the rigor and hard work you have applied here (seemingly).